# Wordpress edit post/page screen is not working

Tags: wordpress, web

I've transferred my wordpress website from a ispmanager to aws EC2. Everything is working fine instead of one thing. I'm unable to edit pages/posts. When I click edit button it redirect to white screen page.

I also tried multiple browsers but return same white screen page.

I found this error in developer console:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier (chrome)

Uncaught SyntaxError: missing } after property list (firefox)

I deactivated all plugins and tried edit posts/pages but gave same results

How Can I fix this issue?

After Enable debug mode I found this errors :
[image]

Comment: Start with enable debug mode, edit wp-config.php and set WP_DEBUG to true. Then may be you will see some error message which cause that.

Comment: @cjmling I uploaded screen shot of error messages on above

Answer (score 1):

**It seems something related to your theme. Try switching themes.**

some other possible solutions

1. Double-check your PHP version should be the same as the previous host
2. Increasing the Memory Limit
3. Disable all plugins
4. If not working u can try with the Classic Editor plugin & Gutenberg you can switch between these & see what works for you.

Comment: 4th solutions was working. I tried with Classic Editor plugin. It is working fine. Thanks for your reply